# jquery scroller not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroller

I'm trying to build a custom scroller that contains inline-block elements. There will always be multiple rows and columns of items within the scroller. The desired effect is to have all currently visible items scroll left/right in unison.

Currently, I am getting a weird result as you can see in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/GR9ZR/2/

current animation:

```
if(direction == 'left'){
    item.animate({'left': -(item.position().left)});
} else {
    item.animate({'right': -(item.position().left)});
}
```

Comment: I saw the demo on js fiddle. Are you trying to build a weekly or monthly calender with task items?

Comment: This will be a monthly calendar.

Comment: If you dont want to user your own plug=in, this might help: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: the calendar is not what I need help implementing. I am trying to implement a simple scroller. I cannot use one off of the shelf because I have additional functionality that is not available in any of the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding units (for example, px) to the animate function like this

```
if(direction == 'left'){
 item.animate({'left': -(item.position().left) +'px'});
} else {
  item.animate({'right': -(item.position().left) + 'px'});
}
```

The left property returns just a number. You might need units for actual animation to occur.

Comment: That still doesn't provide the carousel like animation that I'm trying to achieve. also, the items that are not shown on the first screen momentarily appear at the bottom and don't scroll into view properly.